# CrypTool - How to determine what type of encryption has been used?

Tags: encryption, decryption, cryptanalysis

I have a few questions about CrypTool.

1. How can you use the text analysis tools available in CrypTool to determine the encryption algorithm for a given ciphertext?
2. How can you use CrypTool's text analysis tools to determine the password used for encryption?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**The menu of CrypTool:**
[image]